# FrameworkElement to Image

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am trying to convert a Telerik map to Image.

Telerik has an `ExportToImage` method that works for a map created in View.

But in this case I create a map dynamically and not in View.

When I use `PrintVisual` I see the map perfectly,

But when I use all kinds of methods that convert `FrameworkElement` to Image,

including Telerik's `ExportToImage`, I only get a picture of the Layers inside the map.

```
private void LocationsToImage(ICollection<LocationType> locationCollection, Size size)
{
    var map = new RadMap
    {
        Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.Name),
        Width = size.Width,
        Height = size.Height
    };
    var layer = new InformationLayer();
    map.Items.Add(layer);
    MapHelper.DrawLocations(map, layer, locationCollection);

    //print 
    map.Arrange(new Rect(size));
    map.Measure(size);
    map.Provider = MapProviderFactory.Create();

    var path = @"C:\Test.png";

    SaveToPng(map, path);
}

void SaveToPng(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, encoder);
}

void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
    encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

    using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

And the result I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mpFF.png)

Instead of a normal map, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsYW1.png)

Would appreciate help

Comment: Have you tried to set `map.Provider` before calling Measure and Arrange (which should also be called in that order)?

Comment: If I set the ```map.Provider``` before calling Measure and Arrange I get a blank image, even without the layers

Comment: And when you set map.Provider before adding the InformationLayer?

Comment: I get the same result, blank image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to wait for the **map to load**, try doing this:

```
map.Provider = MapProviderFactory.Create();
await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
```

And then save to image